# How does one use Selenium Webdriver : to choose text from a dynamic combobox with tag <aria-activedescendant>?

Tags: selenium

This is the html:

```
<select select2="" id="id_event_operator" value.bind="model.operator" 
style="width:100%;display:block" class="au-target select2-hidden-accessible" 
au-target-id="134" data-select2-id="id_event_operator" tabindex="-1" aria- 
hidden="true"> <option model.bind="op.id" class="au-target" au-target-id="135" 
data-select2-id="2">--- None ---</option><option model.bind="op.id" class="au- 
target" au-target-id="135" data-select2- 
id="11">liveeventuplynktest01@test.com</option><option model.bind="op.id" 
class="au-target" au-target-id="135" data-select2- 
id="12">uplynkcmsseleniumtestaccount@test.com</option><!--anchor--> </select>


<span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default select2- 
container--below select2-container--open" dir="ltr" data-select2-id="1" 
style="width: 100%;"><span class="selection">

<span class="select2-selection 
select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria- 
expanded="true" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="select2-id_event_operator- 
container" aria-owns="select2-id_event_operator-results" aria- 
activedescendant="select2-id_event_operator-result-q5d6- 
liveeventuplynktest01@test.com">

<span class="select2-selection__rendered" 
id="select2-id_event_operator-container" role="textbox" aria-readonly="true" 
title="--- None ---">--- None ---</span>

<span class="select2-selection__arrow" 
role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span></span></span>

<span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
```

The value of the "aria-activedescendant" keeps on changing as I hover over the elements in the combobox.

How can I grab the value in combobox and set it to the textbox element.Clicking on the "class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" element is not setting the textbox value when I am doing it through the code, but it works if I manually do it from UI.

[This is how the web page looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eww8q.png)

This is my code:

```
public class LiveEventsPage extends PageObject {

@FindBy(xpath = "/html/body/router- 
view/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/form/ul/li[1]/span/span[1]/span/span[2]")
private WebElement eventOperatorDropDownButton;

public void setEventOperator(String dropDownElem){
    waitForElemToBeClickable(eventOperatorDropDownButton).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@aria- 
    activedescendant,'liveeventuplynktest01@test.com')]")).click();
}
}
```

Comment: Where are you stuck exactly? What are the _Manual Steps_ which you are trying to _Automate_? Update the question with the relevant _HTML_ please.

Comment: Update your question, which exact value you wants to target from HTML code.

Comment: @DebanjanB The manual steps I need to automate are: 1) Click on the drop down button. 2) Choose the value from the drop down/ combobox.

Comment: @IshitaShah I need to get this value:"aria-activedescendant="select2-id_event_operator-result-rpgu-uplynkcmsseleniumtestaccount@test.com"

Comment: What language are you using? Can you show a little bit more of the relevant HTML so the second choice of the combobox is also visible?

Comment: @Frank I am using Java, this is all the HTML, there is no second choice, the choice keep on dynamically updating for the tag "aria-activedescendant"

Comment: Is an exception thrown?

Answer (score 0):

Locate with this Xpath :

```
 if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@aria-labelledby='select2-id_event_operator-container']")).isDisplayed())
 {
 String getData = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@aria-labelledby='select2-id_event_operator-container']")).getAttribute("aria-activedescendant");
 }
```

Comment: @The problem with the above approach is that the value "select2-id_event_operator-result-rpgu-uplynkcmsseleniumtestaccount@test.com" is not always the same. The code "rpgu" is different every time.